# Collecting data from multiple sources and saving it in a local database

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, object-relational-model

What would be the ideal solution to periodically/automatically pull the data from different sources (Db2, mysql, xml ect) and store this data locally in XML format or in DB?

PHP is my preferred language.

Is Object relational mapping a solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For periodic scheduling of jobs, have a look at `cron` (assuming your on a Linux machine).  A `cron` job is language agnostic and can run anything that can be run from the command line.

Object Relational Mapping (ORM) is a technique to map database tables to objects.  While you can use this to help solve your problem, it is not really relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Cron job sounds like the perfect solution to periodically run scripts but like you said ORM does not look like a perfect solution to my problem. Do you think using ETL tools would be a better solution?

Comment: Well, if you need to transform the data then yes, otherwise just a small PHP script the pulls data from each database and stores it will be much simpler to implement and maintain.